# SlidingDraw layout over ListView layout possible?

Tags: android, android-listview, slidingdrawer, custom-lists

I'm wondering if it's possible - and therefore how - to put a SlidingDraw over a listView?  The situation is: I have a custom list adapter - inflates layouts and all that - that creates a list.  I would like to put a sliding draw over this list.  But when I try to set the main layout as the xml file with the SlidingDrawer code I get force close because I believe it is interfering with the adapter.  Thanks for any advice.

here is the bulk of my code:

```
public class BandApp extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //this is where I have a problem
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        Activity activity = this;
        activity.setTitle("Title");

        final String[] values = {"(where i put some urls)","@","@","@","@"};

        MyAdapter Adapter = new MyAdapter(this, values);
        setListAdapter(Adapter);
```

When I remove the setContentView it works, when I add it, it doesn't (force close).  But this is where the xml layout with the SlideDrawer is. :/  Thanks for any help

this is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/content">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@id/handle"
         android:layout_width="88dip"
         android:layout_height="44dip" />

     <GridView
         android:id="@id/content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     </SlidingDrawer>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it, it perfectly works in my app. Indeed in my case inside the SlidingDrawer I have a GridView. Here some pieces of the xml file:

```
...
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    />

<SlidingDrawer
     android:id="@+id/drawer"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:handle="@+id/handle"
     android:content="@+id/browse_all_grid_view">

     <Button android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="Pull out text"/>

     <GridView
         android:id="@+id/browse_all_grid_view"
         android:background="@drawable/background_dark"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
         android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
         android:numColumns="2"
         />

</SlidingDrawer>
...
```

Comment: Thanks but what im wondering is if its possible to use a listadapter as the main activity, and then put a slideDrawer over the list.

Comment: yep, I don't understand what's your exact problem. If the app crash on setContent it does not depend on the SlidingDrawer. Have you set the ListView in the main.xml with this id? android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: The setContentView(R.id.main) should load the xml file with the slidingDrawer, making this the view that slides over my listadapter.  When i put the setContentView in with the slidingdrawer xml layout it crashes, when i take it out it works but only shows the listadapter, obviously, because there is no slidingdraw layout anymore.